# How to change jars in web INF lib directory

Tags: java, maven, jar, war, maven-plugin

After creating my war file with mvn package, war file include web/INF lib folder. In that folder, there are some jars which I did not prefer because of the versions of jar.
I cannot manage the version of these jars directly. Some spring plugins/packages manages this.
I tried to increase the versions of plugins which in pom.xml but it did not bring exact version which I need.

How can I change it with mvn commands or pom.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a clear view of the hierarchy of dependencies with this command:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

To exclude a jar from the war, you need to specify the scope with "provided" value. So, you need to add (for a dependency of a dependency) or change the corresponding dependency block:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Another way is to configure the plugin that does the magic:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-5.3.19.jar</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Bingo!, Thank you! <packagingExcludes> worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your project have some jars in web/INF lib,there can not change with mvn.
You should find this jars what you want version in internet,download and replace.

But I suggest you use mvn manage this jars.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I dont want to replace jars manually, I must specify the jars which will go into the my package. It is ridiculous.

Comment: Not at all. The upstairs suggest You can try